How to customize sorting in ag grid server side model in angular?
Currently, I am working on a project and adding an ag-Grid server-side model to it. Now, I want to customize the sorting in ag-Grid, and I am using Angular. I implemented sorting, but the problem I face is that it has multiple sorting options. If the column sort is 'asc' and 'desc', it is working fine, but when the sort is 'null', I want to remove it from the array that I created.
 onSortChange(event: { columnApi: { getColumnState: () => 
 ColumnState[] } }) {
     const sortedColumn = event.columnApi
     .getColumnState()
     .find((col) => Boolean(col.sort));

     const payLoad = this.dataTableService.getPayload(this.tableId());
     let sort: IAgGridSortModel[] = payLoad.sortModel || [];

     if (sortedColumn) {
     const existingSortModelIndex = sort.findIndex(
     (item) => item.sort_by === sortedColumn.colId);
     if (existingSortModelIndex !== -1) {
        sort[existingSortModelIndex].sort_order = sortedColumn.sort ?? 'asc';
  } else {
    sort.push({
      sort_by: sortedColumn.colId,
      sort_order: sortedColumn.sort ?? 'asc'
    });
  }
} else {
  sort = [];
}

this.dataTableService.setPayload(this.tableId(), { sortModel: sort });
this.dataTableService.triggerReload(this.tableId());
}

I use this code now for sorting and it work finely including for multipule sorting but the problem is when the sort is null i wantt to remove the column which comes with sort null and remove it from this sort array
